# how to loop through .py files using importlib

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am trying to use the prefix modl and iterate through .py files that I use as settings. I'd like to stick to python files because it is easy to declare functions and variables and import them. The problem I run into is that the module does not update at the second iteration:

```
for settingsfile in ['settings1.py', 'settings2.py']:
    modl = importlib.import_module(settingsfile)
    var1 = modl.var1
    print('the variable:', var1)
```

output:

```
the variable:var1_from_settings1
the variable:var1_from_settings1
```

Comment: I think you should try without adding the extention `.py` to your setting files.

Comment: What are the contents of `settings1.py` and `settings2.py`?